# PHP modify suhosin settings on runtime

Tags: php, phpunit, suhosin

Is it possible to modify Suhosin settings on runtime execution? I'm asking because PHPUnit uses some features that are disabled by Suhosin (like vfs protocol and eval for mocking) and I'd like to modify those settings in my test bootstrap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `suhosin.session.cryptkey` can be set by ini_set() during runtime.
Most other options can be  set in .htaccess on a per directory basis. This must be enabled explicitly using `suhosin.perdir`,

Example: Allow `suhosin.post.*` to be changed by .htaccess:

```
suhosin.perdir=p
```

See also: http://suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html#suhosin-perdir